# converting URI into svg file using power automate or in power apps

Tags: svg, uri, powerapps, power-automate

is it possible to convert this URI into a svg in power automate:

data:image/svg+xml,%0D%0A%3Csvg%20height%3D%27100%25%27%20width%3D%27100%25%27%20viewBox%3D%271%20600%201500%201%27%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27%3E%0D%0A%3Ctext%20x%3D%27152.5%27%20y%3D%2747.97979798%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3E66%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%2755.55555556%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3E6%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27106.06060606%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EA%20person%20tcho%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27131.31313131%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Enever%20made%20a%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27116.16161616%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EI%20have%20no%20special%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27143.93939394%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Etalent.%20I%20am%20only%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271015%27%20y%3D%27128.78787879%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EImagination%20Es%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27180%27%20y%3D%27159.09090909%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Emistake%20never%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27181.81818182%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Etried%20anything%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27169.19191919%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Epassionately%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271015%27%20y%3D%27156.56565657%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Emore%20important%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27207.07070707%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Enew.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27194.44444444%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ecurious.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27181.81818182%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ethan%20knowledge.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271020%27%20y%3D%27214.64646465%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EALBERT%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27185%27%20y%3D%27239.8989899%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EALBERT%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27227.27272727%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EALBERT%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27250%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EEINSTEIN%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27239.8989899%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EEINSTEIN%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27180%27%20y%3D%27262.62626263%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EKINSTEIN%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27150%27%20y%3D%27406.56565657%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3E66%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27575%27%20y%3D%27416.66666667%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3E56%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27388.88888889%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3E6%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27464.64646465%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EIt%27s%20not%20that%20It%27s%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271015%27%20y%3D%27452.02020202%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EThe%20important%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27180%27%20y%3D%27489.8989899%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Enot%20that%20I%27m%20so%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27474.74747475%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3ELife%20is%20like%20riding%20a%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27479.7979798%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ething%20is%20not%20to%20stop%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27180%27%20y%3D%27515.15151515%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Esmart%3B%20it%27s%20just%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27502.52525253%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ebicycle.%20To%20keep%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27505.05050505%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Equestioning.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27537.87878788%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ethat%20I%20stay%20with%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27525.25252525%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Eyour%20balance%20you%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27525.25252525%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3ECuriosity%20has%20its%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27180%27%20y%3D%27563.13131313%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Eproblems%20longer.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27550.50505051%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Emust%20keep%20moving.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27550.50505051%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Eown%20reason%20for%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27595.95959596%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EALBERT%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27585.85858586%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EALBERT%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27575.75757576%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Eexisting.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27180%27%20y%3D%27621.21212121%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EKINSTEIN%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27606.06060606%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EEINSTEIN%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271020%27%20y%3D%27608.58585859%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EALBERT%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271020%27%20y%3D%27633.83838384%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EEINSTEIN%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27310%27%20y%3D%27661.61616162%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Einapit.%2099%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27732.5%27%20y%3D%27661.61616162%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Einapit.%2099%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271150%27%20y%3D%27661.61616162%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Einjenine%2099%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27750%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3E6%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27180%27%20y%3D%27820.70707071%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EWe%20cannot%20solve%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27808.08080808%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EYou%20have%20to%20learn%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27820.70707071%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3ENo%20problem%20can%20be%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27180%27%20y%3D%27848.48484848%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Eour%20problems%20with%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27833.33333333%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ethe%20rules%20of%20the%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27845.95959596%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Esolved%20from%20the%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27185%27%20y%3D%27873.73737374%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ethe%20same%20thinking%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27861.11111111%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Egame.%20And%20then%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27871.21212121%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Esame%20level%20of%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27896.46464646%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ewe%20used%20when%20we%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27883.83838384%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Eyou%20have%20to%20play%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27906.56565657%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ebetter%20than%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271015%27%20y%3D%27896.46464646%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Econsciousness%20that%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27921.71717172%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ecreated%20them.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271017.5%27%20y%3D%27921.71717172%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Ecreated%20it.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27180%27%20y%3D%27954.54545455%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EALBERT%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27597.5%27%20y%3D%27931.81818182%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3Eanyone%20else.%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27600%27%20y%3D%27964.64646465%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EALBERT%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271020%27%20y%3D%27954.54545455%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EALBERT%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%27182.5%27%20y%3D%27977.27272727%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3EBINSTEIN%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%271020%27%20y%3D%27977.27272727%27%20font-family%3D%27Arial%27%20font-size%3D%2716%27%20fill%3D%27black%27%3ECINSTEN%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0D%0A

im trying to make it into a svg but when i save it as a .svg it says the xml file does not have a specified style

Comment: Something's wrong with how you're saving it then because what you've pasted is an SVG already, it's just encoded as a data URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Automate provides you with the `encodeUriComponent()` and `decodeUriComponent()` functions to convert strings into URL-safe strings and vice-versa.

[See this article](https://www.shahryarsultan.com/2021/12/power-automate-functions-EncodeURIComponent-DecodeURIComponent%20.html)

If need be, you can use them in a flow that can be called from an app and return the decoded svg string:

[Microsoft documentation about responding to apps](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/return-data-to-powerapps/)